# How to detect if Perl code is being run inside an eval?

Tags: perl

I've got [a module](https://metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/lazy-0.000006/lib/lazy.pm#L87-89) that uses an `@INC` hook and tries to install missing modules as they are `use`d.  I don't want this behaviour to fire inside an `eval`.  My attempt to do this currently is:

```
return
    if ( ( $caller[3] && $caller[3] =~ m{eval} )
    || ( $caller[1] && $caller[1] =~ m{eval} ) );
```

That's the result of me messing around with the call stack in some experiments, but it's not catching everything, like this code in [HTTP::Tinyish](https://metacpan.org/source/MIYAGAWA/HTTP-Tinyish-0.14/lib/HTTP/Tinyish.pm#L52-65):

```
sub configure_backend {
    my($self, $backend) = @_;
    unless (exists $configured{$backend}) {
        $configured{$backend} =
          eval { require_module($backend); $backend->configure };
    }
    $configured{$backend};
}

sub require_module {
    local $_ = shift;
    s!::!/!g;
    require "$_.pm";
}
```

Maybe I just need to traverse every level of the call stack until I hit an `eval` or run out of levels.  Is there a better or easier way for me to figure out whether or not code is being wrapped in an `eval` without traversing the call stack?

---

Post mortem on this question:

- as was suggested by multiple posters, this was basically a bad idea
- `$^S` is technically a correct way to do this, but it doesn't let you know if you're inside an `eval` that was called somewhere higher in the stack
- using a regex + `Carp::longmess()` seems to be the most concise way to figure this out
- knowing if code is running inside an `eval` may be somewhat helpful for informational purposes, but since this could be happening for many different reasons, it's very hard to infer why it's happening
- regardless, this was an interesting exercise. i thank all contributors for their helpful input

Comment: Could it be an XY problem? Please provide a wider context - why do you need to check for `eval`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you wouldn't also want to lazy install inside an `eval`.

Comment: I don't want it to try to install optional dependencies as those may be OS-specific or depend on other things that I can't reasonably assume will be there.  These kinds of checks I'd expect to find inside an `eval`, so I'd like those to be a no-op.  In the case of `HTTP::Tinyish`, it can fall back to some other dependency if the `eval` doesn't work out.  I could add an option to try the install in the `eval` case, but for the default this would lead to less problems, I think.

Comment: @oalders There's many other reasons to call `require` inside an `eval`, you might be writing yourself a big headache. Also, have a look at the [code from perl5i::RequireMessage](https://metacpan.org/source/MSCHWERN/perl5i-v2.13.2/lib/perl5i/2/RequireMessage.pm) that ensures your code is always at the end of `@INC`. Otherwise your trigger might pushed down into the stack and fire too early.

Comment: @Schwern I appreciate that feedback. This is mostly just a fun bit of code. Having said that, what got me started on this is looking at these kinds of test failures where (for some reason) LWP is trying to get installed as part of the test suite: http://www.cpantesters.org/cpan/report/1e399162-8978-11e8-8fb1-ef5133556b3f  `cpm` => `HTTP::Tinyish` seems to be where this might be happening.  There are some other circular requirements from some reporters.  I wanted to exclude the eval as being part of the problem, though I don't know why it would be in this case.

Comment: I actually want `lazy` to run in the middle of `@INC` because after a (possibly) successful install I wanted the code to traverse `@INC` once more in an attempt to load the new module.  So the order is original `@INC` => `lazy` => original `@INC`. Do you think that's problematic?

Comment: @oalders The main issue is keeping it there in the middle and ensuring that changes to `@INC` later don't mess things up. For example, what happens with `use lazy; use lib ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Carp::longmess` traverses the stack for you in one call, if that makes things easier

```
return if Carp::longmess =~ m{^\s+eval }m
```

Answer (score 5):

If [$^S](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-the-interpreter-state) is true, the code is inside an `eval`.

```
sub foo { print $^S }
eval { foo() };  # 1
foo();           # 0
```

Comment: Thanks @Schwern! I've tried it out, but `$^S` is actually `undef` at the point that I'm checking.  See https://gist.github.com/oalders/d4ead6895cb282dca38f7623808c44ec

Comment: @oalders `undef` means the interpreter is "Parsing module, eval, or main program" which I guess includes being in a `require`. You might have to resolve `undef` by walking the call stack.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to do this in reusable code.  There are many reasons to be in an eval and not want this kind of action at a distance change.

Comment: I agree with this. I'm writing re-usable code, but it's not *serious* code.  Basically a rewrite of Acme::Magic::Pony. For now I'll add a `warn` about the behaviour under `eval` in each case where there's a no-op. In future I'll probably add a flag to allow the user to specify behaviour under `eval`. One case I found that I want to allow is the use of `Capture::Tiny` which does use `eval`, but isn't a case where I want to bypass installing a module. This is mostly just a fun exercise.